# TSQL Error Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> The Column <Column_Name> cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of union Operator

Please help me how to get rid of this error in TSQL

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: **That** script will not generate **that** error message.

Comment: Don't try to insert / update a value in `[FullDescription]` in your insert or update statement

Comment: Thanks That Was helpful

Comment: It is not an error to get rid of. It is exactly what the message says. Your FullDescription column is a computed column. You don't modify it, you modify the content of the fields that it depends on (diagnosis and description).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-271.aspx

> If a computed column is used as a target of an INSERT or UPDATE
>   statement, this error message will be encountered.

A number of solutions are described:

> To avoid encountering this error message in an INSERT statement,
>   simply don’t include the computed column in the list of columns being
>   populated:
>
> Similarly in the case of an UPDATE statement, instead of updating the
>   computed column directly, update the column that is part of the
>   expression used by the computed column.
>
> Alternatively, if the value in the computed column needs to be
>   different from the values of the columns referenced by the computed
>   column, then one other option is to convert the computed column into
>   an actual column.

Comment: thanks that was helpful